# Capture network interface name with Packetbeat

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, networking, elastic-beats, packetbeat

With Packetbeat on Linux, the `packetbeat.interfaces.device: any` configuration captures all messages sent or received by the server where Packetbeat is installed.

I want to distinguish the messages captured by the interface over which they were exchanged e.g. which messages were exchanged over interface `eth0` and which ones were exchanged over `wlan0`. From the logs, I couldn't find a field with this information.

Is there a way to include the interface device name with Packetbeat logs using some configuration? If not, are there any alternative ways that I could go about capturing the same with the Packetbeat logs?